# What is the best way to pass single variables to a function with multiple arguments locally

Tags: javascript, function, argument-passing

My app is considerably huge. There’s a part that I need to pass two variables generated from different functions to the third function that process them.

My code example looks like this:

```
function one() {
    img = canvas.toDataURL();
}

function two() {
    time = audioContext.currentTime;
}
```

I want them both filled in this function:

```
function tree(i,t) {
    this.i = i;
    this.t = t;
    // do something with i and t
}
```

All the functions are running in sync and have long life span. The only way I can think of now is set variables globally. How do I pass those variables locally, provided that the argument ***i*** in the third function must be always images.

Thank you,

Comment: Your question makes no sense as written.  Functions run one at a time.  When they create some data, you either call another function and pass that data to it or you store that data somewhere (in a global variable or as a property of some object) or you return the data as part of the return value of the function and leave it to the caller to do something with the data.  Also, what does this mean: "All the functions are running in sync and have long life span"?

Comment: The image is on canvas. I can pick picture anytime I want. So it run as long as video still running.

Comment: It only runs when some event occurs that calls it.  It's not running until then.

Comment: Yes, when I trigger function zero, function one, two, three are all run. One generates var i, two generate var t, and I want to put them all in function three.

Comment: So, does iJay's answer solve your problem or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
function one() {
            var img = canvas.toDataURL();
            return img;
        }

        function two() {
            var time = audioContext.currentTime;
            return time;
        }
        function tree(i,t) {
            this.i = i;
            this.t = t;
            // do something with i and t
        }

        var i = one();
        var t = two();
        tree(i, t);
```